# Python: passing arguments to a function

Tags: python, dlib

I am using `dlib`'s `find_min_global` function, an optimization algorithm which helps to find values which minimize the output of a function. For example

```
import dlib
def holder_table(x0,x1):
    return -abs(sin(x0)*cos(x1)*exp(abs(1-sqrt(x0*x0+x1*x1)/pi)))

x,y = dlib.find_min_global(holder_table, 
                           [-10,-10],  # Lower bound constraints on x0 and x1 respectively
                           [10,10],    # Upper bound constraints on x0 and x1 respectively
                           80)         # The number of times find_min_global() will call holder_table()
```

Here the `holder_table` function returns the value that needs to be minimized for different values of `x0` and `x1`.

Here the `holder_table` function takes in only the values that need to be optimized that is `x0` and `x1`. But the function that I want to use with the `dlib` function takes more than `x0` and `x1`. The function definiton looks like so

```
def holder_table(a,b,x0,x1):
    return -abs(sin(b*x0/a)*cos(x1)*exp(abs(1-sqrt(x0*x0+x1*x1)/pi)))
```

The values `a, b` are not fixed and are the outputs of another function. Now, I can directly call the function the returns `a, b` inside the `holder_table` but I dont want to end up re-calculating them because each time `holder_table` is called `a, b`  gets re-calculated and the process is time consuming.

How do I pass `a, b`  to the `holder_table` function?

Comment: Can you include the bit of your code that computes a and b please?

Comment: @N.Bailey. Sorry, I am not allowed to paste the actual codes. I have tried to produce a minimal example that represents the issue I am facing.

Comment: Am I correct in that you want to run a full optimization run for a specific `a` and `b`?  The `a` and `b` might change, but only between optimization runs - and you want to re-use as much code as possible?

Comment: @jedwards, yes. thats what I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not 100% clear but it looks like you want a [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application). In Python this can be done using the dedicated `functools.partial` object, or quite simply with a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) (using either an inner function or lambda)

```
def holder_table(a,b,x0,x1):
    return -abs(sin(b*x0/a)*cos(x1)*exp(abs(1-sqrt(x0*x0+x1*x1)/pi)))


def main():
    a, b = some_heavy_function(...)
    holder_table_partial = lambda ax, ay: holder_table(a, b, ax, ay)
    x, y = dlib.find_min_global(
        holder_table_partial, [-10,-10], [10,10], 80
        )
```

Comment: @ClockSlave glad I could help - and if this solved your problem then feel free to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Going only by your presentation of the specification, `holder_table` is a function that takes two arguments and returns the final result that can be used to help guide the optimization step.  Also, if I understand correctly, `a` and `b` are components of the objective formula, but might take a while to compute and you don't want the computation of their logic to be called more frequently than necessary -- so including their derivation *inside* the `holder_table` seems inefficient.

What about something like:

```
def build_objective_function(a,b):
    def holder_table(x0,x1):
        return -abs(sin(b*x0/a)*cos(x1)*exp(abs(1-sqrt(x0*x0+x1*x1)/pi)))
    return holder_table
```

And you'd call it like:

```
a = <compute a>
b = <compute b>
holder_table = build_objective_function(a,b)  # holder_table will be a function

x,y = dlib.find_min_global(holder_table, 
                           [-10,-10],  # Lower bound constraints on x0 and x1 respectively
                           [10,10],    # Upper bound constraints on x0 and x1 respectively
                           80)         # The number of times find_min_global() will call holder_table()
```